# Email notification for subversion polling failures in Jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins, continuous-integration

We had a job in Jenkins fail it's subversion polling for over 24 hours due to a password change. It's not immediately obvious when this happens unless you notice jobs aren't running and actually check the logs, the build does not fail since it's never kicked off.

Has anyone found a solution to notify Jenkins admins for any polling failures? My current idea is scheduling either the same or a second job that kicks off periodically just to make sure that the login is valid.

http://jenkins.mycompany.com/view/Builds/job/Trunk/scmPollLog/?

#### Example of Expected Log

```
Started on Aug 16, 2013 11:55:35 AM
Received SCM poll call on  for Trunk on Aug 16, 2013 11:55:35 AM
http://svn.mycompany.com/trunk/sources is at revision 76,283
Done. Took 64 ms
No changes
```

#### Example of Failed Log

```
Started on Aug 16, 2013 11:04:36 AM
Received SCM poll call on  for Trunk on Aug 16, 2013 11:04:36 AM
ERROR: Failed to check repository revision for http://svn.mycompany.com/trunk/sources
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNCancelException: svn: E200015: OPTIONS /trunk/sources failed
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:375)
    ...
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNCancelException: svn: E200015: No credential to try. Authentication failed
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.cancel(SVNErrorManager.java:37)
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins doesn't support this right now, because [polling happens outside of a job context](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11760).

Some ideas:

- **preferred** [polling must die](http://kohsuke.org/2011/12/01/polling-must-die-triggering-jenkins-builds-from-a-git-hook/) if you trigger the job from a [SVN commit hook](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin), I believe the password failure will happens at svn update, thus during the job. You will be notified. You will have the benefit of getting rid of polling as well.
- fix [JENKINS-11760](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11760) ;)